# How to arrange my data in ruby

Tags: ruby

My sincere apologies if my question is very obvious. I'm breaking my head over it and yet to get a viable solution or a logic.

input file below (input.txt)

```
Record: C:/my_files/00_Roll_Tom-values.txt

#RakeBoss-Random as on 12/19/2016
[groups]
met = chk\rel_io_chk, chk\dev_op_io,
div = chk\kzhr2x, chk\zz52t0, chk\czzjrt
rakeonly = chk\rzgnsd, chk\cztw5h

[/]
@met = rw
@div = rw
@rakeonly = r
*******************************************************************************************
Record: C:/my_files/Rander-values.txt

#RakeBoss-Jan 21st QA
[groups]
met = chk\rel_io_chk, chk\dev_op_io
div = chk\541kmj, chk\zz52t0
app_only = chk\zz9ycd
check_io = chk\wder4, chk\zz9ycd
div_write = chk\lo98j3
year_on = chk\3w345f
[/]
@met = rw
@div = rw
@app_only= r
@check_io = r
@div_write = rw
@year_on = r

[/wedmin]
@check_io = rw
div_write= rw

[/doc/prod]
@div = rw
@app_only = r
year_on = rw
*******************************************************************************************
Record: C:/my_files/456_Milo_123-values.txt

#RakeBoss-Jan 21st Prod
[groups]
met = chk\rel_io_chk, chk\dev_op_io
div = chk\kzhr2x, chk\zz52t0, chk\czzjrt, chk\pzjwr3
jee_only = chk\zz9ycd, chk\hz659l, chk\zzktgj, 
check_io = chk\8u7y01, chk\zz9ycd
unique_key = chk\zz9ycd
year_on = chk\dytg6
[/]
@met = rw
@div = rw
@rakeonly = r

[/Release]
@check_io = rw
@unique_key = rw

[/Redmine/Treehub]
@div = r
@jee_only = rw
******************************************************************************************
Record: C:/my_files/Docker_red-values.txt

#RakeBoss-Check it io.
[groups]
met = chk\rel_io_chk, chk\dev_op_io, chk\njk987
div = chk\gzlqvg, chk\zzkgyp, chk\lzg0rp, chk\gzp2kv
rakeonly = chk\qzvjq0, chk\kz6w6t, chk\bzy4kj, chk\dzfbhp

[/]
@met = rw
@div = rw
@rakeonly = r
******************************************************************************************
```

I'm trying to read the input file and write the formatted output to an Excel. Every module or a set is separated by series of '#'. For the 1st set as seen below output should be in the below format

**1st set**

```
Record: C:/my_files/00_Roll_Tom-values.txt

#RakeBoss-Random as on 12/19/2016
[groups]
met = chk\rel_io_chk, chk\dev_op_io,
div = chk\kzhr2x, chk\zz52t0, chk\czzjrt
rakeonly = chk\rzgnsd, chk\cztw5h

[/]
@met = rw
@div = rw
@rakeonly = r
```

Output in excel should be

```
file_name   cluster       id                   case     access_levels

00_Roll_Tom   met        chk\rel_io_chk          /       rw
00_Roll_Tom   met        chk\dev_op_io           /       rw
00_Roll_Tom   div        chk\kzhr2x              /       rw
00_Roll_Tom   div        chk\zz52t0              /       rw
00_Roll_Tom   div        chk\czzjrt              /       rw
00_Roll_Tom   rakeonly   chk\rzgnsd              /       r  
00_Roll_Tom   rakeonly   chk\cztw5h              /       r
```

**For the 2nd set**

```
Record: C:/my_files/Rander-values.txt

#RakeBoss-Jan 21st QA
[groups]
met = chk\rel_io_chk, chk\dev_op_io
div = chk\541kmj, chk\zz52t0
check_io = chk\wder4, chk\zz9ycd
div_write = chk\lo98j3

[/]
@met = rw
@div = rw
@check_io = r
@div_write = r

[/wedmin]
@check_io = rw
div_write= rw

[/doc/prod]
@div = r
```

Output should be in the same format as the 1st set  and so on for the remaining sets.

```
Rander-values   met       chk\rel_io_chk   /            r
Rander-values   met       chk\dev_op_io    /            r
Rander-values   div       chk\541kmj       /            r
Rander-values   div       chk\zz52t0       /            r
Rander-values   check_io  chk\wder4        /            r
Rander-values   check_io  chk\zz9ycd       /            r
Rander-values   div_write lo98j3           /            r
Rander-values   check_io  chk\wder4        /wedmin      rw
Rander-values   check_io  chk\zz9ycd       /wedmin      rw
Rander-values   div_write lo98j3           /wedmin      rw
Rander-values   div       chk\541kmj       /doc/prod    r
Rander-values   div       chk\zz52t0       /doc/prod    r
```

I'm not sure how to process the data or what structure should I consider. I have wen thru multiple documentation and blogs but I couldn't fix one. Any help here is really appreciated. Thanks.

I'm just stuck with the only with the below piece of code and I'm lost how to move forward

```
file = File.open("C:/input.txt", "r").read
data = file.split(/\*+/)
```

Comment: What is the logic that gives you `chk\njk987` in the output of the first set?

Comment: @sawa : Sorry that's an editing mistake, I have corrected the same.

Comment: What is the logic that gives you what you have in the output of the second set? Don't let me repeat. Don't be lazy.

Comment: @sawa I'm sorry, I have just given the expected output . I'm not sure how to get that done. I'm new to ruby and exploring its deep concepts.

Comment: It has nothing to do with Ruby.

Comment: @sawa : Okay , could you kinfly help me here or guide me thru. Thanks.

Comment: @Gerry : Could you kindly help me here.Thanks a lot.